# Convert SAX ContentHandler characters(..) to InputStream

Tags: stream, sax

We wrote a new API which uses SAX API to process documents and allows the caller to pass an instance of SAX ContentHandler which handles SAX events. This works, but we also have legacy code which expects the content as an InputStream.

So, we need to implement SAX ContentHandler which has a getStream() method that returns InputStream with characters received in ContentHandler#characters(..). Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: This is Java, right? ;)  Please post some code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes, it's Java. We don't have much. This is what we are thinking about:
StreamingContentHandler:

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
 {
  // todo: block if the input stream is not being exhausted quickly enough
  String str = new String(ch, start, length);
  out.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  super.characters(ch, start, length);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using BodyContentHandler from Tika and passed PipedOutputStream to it which piped characters to PipedInputStream.